# Visual Studio 2015 Angular2 html variable intellisense / compile checks

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Is there any way to enable intellisense or at least compile time static checks on visual studio 2015 in html files with angular 2 (NOT angular 1) variables?

For example if you have the following typescript somewhere:

```
export class Hero {
    constructor(
      public id:number,
      public name:string) { }
}
```

And for example if you have the following in your html:

```
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <h2>My favorite hero is: {{myHero}}</h2>
  <p>Heroes:</p>
  <ul>
      <li *ng-for="#hero of heroes">
          {{ hero.name }}
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Then I would like intellisense or at least compile checks on the usage of that hero object and its properties. If I type "hero." then I would like to be able to get the "name" property as a suggestion (or if not possible something that can check at compile time whether these properties and classes exist).

Is something like that already available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is something like that already available?

Not at the moment. There might be something *after they have template precompilation working*: https://docs.google.com/document/d/11r8IuS4xDyhVSEBp7fDYo7aiLYsLEXKs4lPd36umUGM/edit

Of course you can use React/TSX quite easily.https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/jsx/tsx.html